# Group Optionals within TypeScript type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an object that needs certain optionals to be grouped. So either none is passed, or both are passed. I would normally add this to a nested property, but I cannot change the shape of this object.

In the example below, there is a required 'a', an optional 'b', but then 'c' and 'd' must either both be supplied, or neither be supplied.

```
type Basic = {
 a: string,
 b? string, // independant

 c?: boolean, // if c is given, d must also be given
 d?: (e: boolean) => void, // if d is given, c must also be given 
}
```

I tried to do some fancy Typescript, but it seems I am not good enough to understand the advanced stuff yet.

```
type GroupedOptional<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: undefined;
} & Required<T>

type Fancy = {
 a: string,
 b?: string,
} & GroupedOptional<{
  c: boolean,
  d: (e: boolean) => void,
}>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
type AllOrNothing<T> = T | Partial<Record<keyof T, undefined>>

type Fancy = {
    a: string,
    b?: string,
} & AllOrNothing<{
    c: boolean,
    d: (e: boolean) => void,
}>;

let t1:Fancy =  { a: ""}
let t2:Fancy =  { a: "", c: true} // err
let t3:Fancy =  { a: "", c: true, d: (e)=> {}} // ok
```

The all or nothing, creates a union between the original `T` and a `Partial` that forces that if the properties are present they should be `undefined` (basically forbidding them)

Comment: AHHHH... I did try something similar to this, but it failed, I didn't wrap the never part in a `Partial` and `Partial` seems to be the key to making it work.  Thank you.